# CSS Transition unwantedly Moves my text. How do I prevent this from happening

Tags: html, css, frontend

So I've been learning front-end development recently, and this problem really bugs me. I wanted to make an on-hover animation for my links.
Here's the code

```css
body{
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(37,37,82,1) 
35%, rgba(38,54,82,1) 100%);
color: white;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#Title{
Font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
}
/*Global*/
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  min-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: #ef3331 3px solid;
}

#branding {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: transparent;
}

header a {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-width: thick;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 16px 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

header a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1>Anđelo Motika Design</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html"> <span>HOME</span> </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> ABOUT ME </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> GALLERY </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

The links keep moving during the page's loading phase. It is not what I want. I just wanna change the background of the a tag, not their position too.
Here's some screencaps to demonstrate my problem.

[image: During loading]

[image: After Loading the page]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This has less to do with your CSS and more with blocking resources as your page loads. Do you have a large image in that header?

Comment: Please update the snippet to demonstrate the problem as it appears in your images. Also, floats are a dated and troublesome strategy. I suggest flexbox or just inline-block layout.

Comment: I'm not using any images for the header. The image under is for another section.

Comment: @AnđeloMotika placement is irrelevant. This still appears to be loading issue, since we can't reproduce it in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the below line from `header a` decorator in css file.

```
transition: 0.3s;
```

Also if you want to add text color while hovering , you can add this on the `header a : hover`

```
 header a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}
```